# Upload multiple files with Tornado Web Server and Nginx

Tags: python, file, file-upload, tornado

I am developing an upload multiple files with Python + Tornado + Nginx Web Server. 
I have changed the properties of the Nginx server as follows:

**client_body_buffer_size 512K; 
client_max_body_size 500M;**

However, when sending a quantity greater than 3 files, it does not forward the room. 
What could be happening?

On the internet and even here on Stack Overflow only examples with a single file, or against, creating multiple

The code is below:

**Python**

```
class UploadHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        try :
            t = len(self.request.files)+1
            x = 0
            n = 'file'
            while x <= t:
                nn = self.request.files[n][x]
                nome_arquivo = nn['filename']
                output_file = open("my directory/" + nome_arquivo, 'w')
                output_file.write(nn['body'])
                x+=1

            self.render(
            "sucess.html"
                )
        except IndexError:
            self.render(
            "sucess.html"
            )
```

**HTML**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/uploads">
<input name="descricao" type="text" /> <br>
<input type="file" name="file" multiple />
<input type="submit" value="Send File(s)">
</form>
```

Comment: What types of files..?

Answer (score 1):

Friends, i solved it creating one index. Before, didn't have it.

**Final resolution:**

```
class UploadHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        try :
            t = len(self.request.files)
            x = 1
            indice = 0
            n = 'file'
            while x <= t:
                nn = self.request.files[n][indice]
                nome_arquivo = nn['filename']
                output_file = open("static/arquivos/" + nome_arquivo, 'w')
                output_file.write(nn['body'])
                indice+=1

            self.render(
            "sucess.html"
                )
        except IndexError:
            self.render(
            "sucess.html" # this necessary but command while don't achieved implement
            )             # x+=1 - i don't know why...
                          # with this resolution, an error will be showed but redirected
                          # at the same if success
```